# base64_Encode content from textarea from a form using php to send via mail

Tags: php

I'm trying to achieve something without success.

I have a contact form with two fields, one is an input for the email address and another is a textarea. I'm trying to convert this text included into an encoded text and print it via mail to the mail included on that same form.

for example, here's my form.

HTML

```
<form action="email.php" method="post" class="form" id="form1">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email...">
            <textarea class="textarea" name="clientMessage" placeholder="Write them something secret here, they won't know who wrote it" maxlength="120"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="sendButton" id="sendButton" value="Send">
            </form>
```

So now I'll try to print this "clientMessage" on the $message .=""; of my mailer.php to send it to the mail introduced on the form. So far I receive the mail but with the code as text. Not sure what I'm doing wrong:

mailer.php

```
<?php
$clientMessage= $_POST["clientMessage"];
echo base64_encode($clientMessage);
$message = '<html><body>';

$message .= "echo base64_encode($clientMessage);";
$message .= "</body></html>";

$sender= $_POST["email"];

$to = $sender;

$subject = 'Something for you';

$from = 'secret@noreply.com';

$fromEmail = 'secret@noreply.com';

$header = 'From: ' . $from . '<' . $fromEmail . '>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header("Location: https://www.website.com/thanks.html");
exit;
?>
```

Someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong:)? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're already in PHP, so the output of `$message .= "echo base64_encode($clientMessage);"` will be that string. Just try `$message .= base64_encode($clientMessage);`

I hope I understood correctly what you meant.

Comment: what if I want to include a web address first? shoudl be
$message .= 'https://www.website.com/index.html?m='+'base64_encode($clientMessage)';

Comment: i guess you did find it. :)

Comment: Indeed thanks @Radu Vlad :D published under this comment:)!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was this one

PHP

```
$clientMessage= $_POST["clientMessage"];
$encodedMessage = "https://www.address.com/read.html?m=";
$encodedMessage .= base64_encode($clientMessage);
```

First of all posting the clientMessage from the form, then creating the link with another variable created used as a link, first of all the address and the termination of the encoded text on the second one. works just fine!